# Solve Margin issues of using nth child for navigation

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I currently have a navigation set up so that My logo is centered in the middle of my navigation. I got the code markup from   [css3 nth child selector](http://stanislav.it/how-to-center-a-logo-in-unordered-list-navigation-using-css3-nth-child-selector/) and it works as expected

I am using wordpress so my markup is a bit different of course

My problem is that am wanting to have a media query that resizes for mobile, but when I resize it keeps the margins that I have set for the desktop nav. Is there a way to make those margins go away or return to default so it doesn't look all spread out when scaled down to mobile size?
I'd like the margins to be different when scaled to mobile.

thanks for viewing

```
  <header class="header">
            <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
               <li>Home</li>
               <li>About</li>
               <li>Services</li>
               <li>Work</li>

        </ul>
           </nav>

    <a class="logo" href="http://www.website.com"></a>

    </header><!--header-->


  header {
  border-top: 5px solid #3399ff;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;


}

 nav li {display: inline-block;}

 nav li:nth-child(1) {

 margin-right: 100px;

}

 nav li:nth-child(2) {

 margin-right: 50px;
  }

 nav li:nth-child(3) {

 margin-left: 50px;

  }

 nav li:nth-child(4) {
 margin-left: 100px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think thats would be possible if you set the margin for the "desktop" version with a media query and for the "mobile version with another media query.

I should look something like these:

`@media (min-width: 768px) { /*insert you desktop css here }`

`@media (max-width: 767px) { /*insert you mobile css here }`

This will use the desktop css if your viewport is 768px or larger or the mobile css if the viewport is 767px or smaller.

Hope that solve your problem.

Comment: just seeing this, yes this works perfectly! I am getting a better handle on media queries.